# How does the nth sample impact Mean and Variance?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, outliers, sample

Given the Mean and Variance of $n$ samples $x_i$:

$$M_n=\frac {1}{n}\sum_{1}^{n}  x_i$$

$$V_n=\frac {1}{n}\sum_{1}^{n}(x_i-μ_n)^2$$

How do Mean and Variance change, when we take into account one more sample?

In other words, what are the function $f(x_n,\space...)$ and $g(x_n,\space...)$ such that:

$$M_n = f(x_n,\space n, \space M_{n-1})$$

$$V_n = g(x_n, \space n, \space M_{n-1}, \space V_{n-1})$$

Thank you!

Comment: Outliers defined as what? Often people define outliers as values that lie some number of standard deviations from the mean. In such case, it gets circular.

Comment: ok I'll remove the word "outlier" to focus my question better. thanks!

Comment: This answer seems to give you what you're looking for: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374881/recursive-formula-for-variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374881/recursive-formula-for-variance)